# Are these topologies equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory

Consider the space $(\mathbb C^2 , τ_1 )$ where $τ_1$ is the product topology on $\mathbb C^2$ with $\mathbb C$ having the Zariski topology
i.e. closed sets indexed by $p(x) \in \mathbb C[x]$ are given as:
$$Z_{p(x)} = \{z \in \mathbb C|p(z) = 0\}$$

Let $m_{(a,b)}$ denote the maximal ideal generated by $x−a$ and $y −b$ in $\mathbb C[x, y]$. Assume that every maximal
ideal in $\mathbb C[x, y]$ is of this form. Define $τ_2$ on $\mathbb C^2$ as the topology which has the following as open sets
indexed by ideals in $\mathbb C[x, y]$:
$$D_I = \{(a, b) \in 
\mathbb C^2 |I \not\subset m_{(a,b)} \}$$

Is $τ_1 = τ_2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at closed sets. For the Zariski topology in $\mathbb C$ they are the finite sets: a polynomial has only finitely many zeroes. Hence the closed sets of the product topology $\tau_1$ are also the finite sets (products of finite sets). Now the topology $\tau_2$. Let $I$ be an ideal  of $\mathbb C[x,y]$. That $I\subset m_{(a,b)}$ just means that all functions $f\in I$ that vanish at $(a,b)$, hence $(a,b)\in\bigcap_{f\in I}\{f=0\}$. Since $I$ is finitely generated, say by $f_1,\dots,f_r\in I$, we have
$$
(a,b)\in\bigcap_{f\in I}\{f=0\}=\{f_1=0,\dots,f_r=0\}=F(f_1,\dots,f_r).
$$
Consequently, the closed sets of $\tau_2$ are $\mathbb C^2\setminus D_I=F(f_1,\dots,f_r)$. Hence this is *the Zariski topology in the complex plane*. Clearly it has many infinite closed sets, so that $\tau_1$ is strictly coarser than $\tau_2$.